# Ain't = have not

Tags: contractions, negation

Can you give me some examples where "ain't" is used in place of "have not".

According to Oxford Dictionary, ain't=am not,is not,are not,has not,have not.

Comment: See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ain%27t#Contractions_of_to_have_not

Comment: _We ain't seen the last of this question..._

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It replaces *have not* when *have not* is an auxiliary verb, not when it's a a conjugation of *to have:*

> > "I have been racking my brain, but I *ain't been* able to come up with a good example."
> >
> > "I have done a lot of bad things, but I *ain't hit* a man with glasses or stolen from a baby."

A very common combination is *"ain't got"* meaning *have not got* (or, briefly, *don't have*)  A google search will reveal that "ain't got" turns up in lyrics all the time:

- Gangsta rap ([UZ's *S**t I Ain't Got*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zbQotxBSSc))
- Guitar blues ([Yardbirds *I Ain't Got You*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_jIrofic1E))
- R&B/Jazz ([Nina Simone's *Ain't Got No*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUcXI2BIUOQ))
- 80's hair rock ([David Lee Roth's *Just a Gigolo/I Ain't Got Nobody*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YD0X5Qu0vtw) )
- Country Western ([Reba McEntire *I Don't Need Nothing You Ain't Got.*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30JeKIS-s5c))
- Folk roots ([Woody Guthrie's *I Ain't Got No Home in This World Anymore*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTnVMulDTYA))

While we generally avoid the double negative in English, you can see in these examples that *"ain't"* often bucks that trend and pairs up with a second negation (nobody, no home, no)

Note: This would not be considered standard written English.  In some parts of the U.S., it would be fairly common to hear it in spoken English (e.g. Texas), but from a second-language speaker, it would sound strange, unless you are *extremely* fluent.

Comment: Unless you're in the south, particularly Texas. Where "ain't" and "ya'll" reign ;)

Comment: I think you mean "Ah dun a heap o' bad things, but Ah ain't never hit no man with glasses nor stole from no baby." :-)

Comment: @catija *Y'all*; *ya'll* is "you will". If y'all'll observe this simple rule ya'll avoid the mockery of Southerners.

Comment: @StoneyB Sorry. I can't fix it now :( I'm not mocking. I'm from Texas and say it all the time, myself.

Comment: @catija No, no: I meant you will avoid being mocked by Southerners. (I too am of that ethnos.)